# ngrx effect's action not triggering reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have my Angular 5 code working without ngrx effect. After adding effect and send HTTP request, I can not trigger reducer to be invoked by an action. My effect is this. This console log is getting hit with the correct http response.

```
@Injectable()
export class PropertyEffects {
@Effect({dispatch: false})
propertyFetch$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$//.pipe(
    .ofType(PropertyActions.FETCH_ALL_PROPERTIES)
    .switchMap(action =>
       this.httpClient.get('https://yxalbf1t6l.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/todos').pipe(
            // If successful, dispatch success action with result
            map(data => {
                console.log(`Success ${JSON.stringify(data)}, 0, 2)`);
                return new PropertyActions.OpenAllProperties(data)
            })
    )
);
```

My reducer for the OpenAllProperties action below was getting called correctly before using effect. With effect, its console log never gets hit.

```
case PropertyListActions.OPEN_ALL_PROPERTIES:
   console.log("in reducer, action.payload: " + JSON.stringify(action.payload,null,2))
        const openAllProperties = !state.openAllProperties;
        return {
            ...state,
            openAllProperties: openAllProperties
        }
```

Please help. thank you!

Comment: I think the `{dispatch: false}` parameter is stopping the action from being passed on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a parameter to stop the dispatching the event. That will not trigger the reducer function because it does not dispatch anything.

If you want to verify it use [redux dev tools](https://github.com/ngrx/store-devtools)

In there you will see all dispatch event in the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
performSearchAction$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(
() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.searchAction),

    switchMap(data =>
      this.apiService.getSearch(data).pipe(
        tap(x => console.log('searchResponseData', x)),
        map(searchResponseData => actions.searchSuccessAction(searchResponseData)),
        catchError(error => of(actions.searchFailureAction(error)))
      )
    )
  ),
{ dispatch: true, resubscribeOnError: false } // dispatch: true
```

);

#### TIP: Remember to set: dispatch: true if using ngrx8